# Why don't English speakers like sentence in the passive form?

Tags: passive-voice, grammar-myths

In my native language (Indonesian), the passive form is used as frequently as the active form, if not more often. So I read passive sentence in English without problem. I also see it more convenient to use the passive form when the subject in the active form is not important in the sentence, and there are lots of cases for that. Why do English speakers usually distaste passive sentence and often advise me to use more active sentences? I would love to hear some background culture influence or thinking process so I can understand it deeper. Thanks.

Comment: That's something that only Willam Strunk and purists  would say!!! You are right, passive is better when the agent is not important. Also, read this Pullum's [paper](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/passive_loathing.pdf&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjZjZCw3YLUAhXhsFQKHTGXA5gQFggLMAA&usg=AFQjCNEfKhNyzvwXMP5E1lTJ9Xj2GYDOTQ)

Comment: That's very subjective. A lot of languages use the passive a lot less than English, and the passive voice can have different uses in different languages. I do not think it belongs to ELL. You might try to ask the question on [linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/), they already have a passive tag,  and I have just found this question [Why can't these English sentences passivize?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/6581/637) that might interest you.

Comment: I think this is a very good question for ELL, because it's about something very puzzling for many non-native speakers: why all the *fuss* about the passive voice? As the OP says, the question is about "background culture". It's not about what kinds of constructions the grammar has passive forms of.

Comment: @Laure in my native Indonesian language, which emphasise on excessive eastern-politeness culture, we usually use passive form when we want to focus the subject on the object, and lift the "responsibility" or "burden" from the subject. So instead of asking "Why *you* opened the door?" we ask "Why is this door opened?" --> which can mean that we do not judge anybody for why this door was opened (or maybe we just don't know who open the door at the first place, so we use passive form to omit that).

Comment: @Laure That is the cultural background of why my language uses more passive sentence than active, and it's somewhat like become a second nature when forming a sentence in English for me. So I would like to know the same in English speakers, so I can internalise it and possibly can get rid of passive voice when forming English sentence if I understand what it meant for English speakers to prefer to write in active than passive.

Comment: @user178049 thanks for the paper. I'm reading it right now. :)

Comment: @ChenLiYong As a native Malay speaker, I strongly agree with the idea that "why is the door open? " sounds more polite than "Why did you open the door?". I think this question is too broad, but it's indeed good question! :)

Comment: [Discussed on English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/is-using-passive-voice-bad-form).  This issue is certainly not unique to learners - native speakers also frequently face confusion and disagreement over when to use the passive voice.

Comment: I could've posted an answer, but I don't know how to add a picture in an answer. So I just write my idea by here. The force of using active voice is popularized William Strunk in his The Element of Style. The book was very popular that many of the guidance (including "use active voice") still exists now.

Comment: But I believe the use of passive voice depends heavily on the register and clarity. In academic prose and news for example, the actor of the action is usually unknown or unimportant. That's why the short passive is used. (I have the chart of the use of short passive accross register; I just don't know how to put that in a post).

Comment: Another factor is clarity. It depends on the **end-weight** , **end-focus** and **information-flow** principle. (I hope you google those names)

Comment: Please wait another day or two before accepting an answer. This is a non-trivial question, and you should see a variety of thoughtful answers and commentary before you settle on one.

Comment: @BenKovitz okay, I'll very much welcoming all inputs about this so I can see from various perspective. Thanks!

Comment: While browing this topic on internet, I found this [interesting series of videos](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=kcbHKbvwCnU) by Geoffrey K. Pullum.

Comment: @user178049 I haven't watched the videos, but I recommend taking anything Pullum says about this with a grain of salt. For example, he takes Orwell to task for violating his own "rule" against the passive, but here's what Orwell actually said: "Break any of these rules sooner than say anything outright barbarous" and "I have not here been considering the literary use of language, but merely language as an instrument for expressing and not for concealing or preventing thought." This is not the first time I've caught Pullum misrepresenting other people's views in order to make them look stupid.

Comment: This is a language question, specifically about pragmatics.  It should not be closed, and isn't really much about culture, although that does play a small role.

Comment: @snailplane As I understand it, the question has a false premise: English speakers don't really dislike sentences in passive form. People _advise_ against the passive voice because they've been _taught_ that the passive voice is bad. They _think_ they dislike it, but really it doesn't bother them. I think the OP is right to ask about "background culture influence or thinking process" to sort out the weirdness. But it sounds like you might have an angle on this that I haven't considered. Post an answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what happened.

## The Golden Age

Once upon a time, people throughout the English-speaking world used the active
voice and the passive voice according to whichever seemed to suit what they
were trying to say. No one attached moral opprobrium to either, the people
were happy, and there was peace throughout the land.*

Some human pursuits, such as administration and science, needed to make heavy
use of the passive voice, because these pursuits are largely concerned with
rules and results that are independent of the person who carried them out.
Any competent member of the civil service should produce the same
results given the same rules as any other. "The claimant's petition for a
hunting license **is denied**, pursuant to §12345.67(g) of the Hunting Code."
The result of a scientific experiment should depend on what was done, not who
did it. "0.5 gm tin **was heated** to [15,000,000 ºC](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/333542/68594)." Mentioning the name of the
lab assistant who heated it would distract from the important facts, so the
passive voice is appropriate. Similarly for bank tellers, accountants,
optometrists, engineers, etc.

The language used by people in these pursuits was, and still is, precise,
formal, and objective—"objective" in the sense that the person who "did" the
action is irrelevant. The relationship between writer and reader is
*impersonal*. You don't negotiate with administrators or scientists, finding a
compromise between your and their unique desires and situations. They merely
report results. And these people get a lot of prestige and respect.

## The Fall

It gradually dawned on people that if they wanted to sound formal and
objective—and to get some of the respect given to professionals—they could use
the passive voice even when it doesn't make sense or help communicate a
thought.  "It is imperative that steps **are delineated** for the establishing of
time frames for socioeconomic priorities by responsible authorities."
Similarly for highly abstract language, heavy use of the verb "to be", "big
words" that derive from Latin, and other usage that's often needed
legitimately in technical professions.
When applied to most ordinary
writing, such stylistic choices make the writing weak and unclear.
"With regard to my summer vacation, the locations **visited** were **felt** to be
memorable for a lifespan."
I made up these last two examples as absurd parodies, but people were indeed 
imitating the sound
of formal writing rather than *using* its conventions to communicate clearly.

By around 1910, many English teachers had noticed that students were resorting
to pretentious, dull phrasing in their writing in an attempt to sound educated
or formal. So they started advising their students to
cut it out. Some produced pamphlets containing advice on how to write more
clearly and forcefully. Today, the most famous of these is [Strunk & White](https://books.google.com/books?id=sj5_wr6zIEcC&pg=PA33&dq=active%20voice), a
little handbook of advice to counter various bad stylistic choices that were
common among college students in the early 20th century.

## The Plot-Twist

Now here's where our story starts to turn weird. Many schoolteachers are
themselves the kind of people who maintain the stability of their society by
upholding strict rules. They try to measure the performance of their students
fairly and in conformity with the professional standards of their time, not
according to their own "subjective" judgement. This has led schoolteachers
many times to reduce good advice that requires thoughtful case-by-case
judgement to foolish strict rules. Strict rules, foolish or not, are much
easier to teach, enforce, and measure conformity to than good judgement.
Good judgement is something you gradually cultivate, and it emerges in a
unique form in each individual. No standardized test can measure that.

Once it had emerged among the most respected English teachers that the
passive voice was often abused, rank-and-file schoolteachers began to "teach"
that the passive voice was not just easy to abuse, but *wrong.* It's not just
unclear, it's an attempt to dodge moral responsibility! Indeed the passive
has always been the voice of choice for weasels, responsibility-dodgers, and
obscurantists. George W. Bush [famously said](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ga5JCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA182&dq=%22He+heard+a+bird+flush,+and+he+turned+and+pulled+the+trigger%22) "He heard a bird flush, and he
turned and pulled the trigger and saw his friend **get wounded**." That's Bush's
way of saying "Dick Cheney shot his friend Harry Whittington with a rifle in a
hunting accident" but taking care that you don't understand it. There's no
limit to the number of examples of this kind of weaselly use of the passive
voice that you can find to prove that the passive is *evil.* Of course, you can find just as many dishonest uses of every other grammatical form, too. People
use the active voice to outright lie, but only the passive voice is the
target of a moral crusade.

And so, every passive construction in an essay written by a student would be
marked "passive" in red ink, with points taken off. Excuse me, I mean **the
schoolteachers** would mark every passive construction that **the student
wrote** and **take points off**. Whew, I almost sank into moral depravity for
a moment there. Even when passive constructions specified the agent, as in
"Harry Whittington was shot by Dick Cheney", teachers would mark it in red and
penalize it.  Many innocent constructions that merely look similar to the
passive but aren't, like "The truck is now loaded," also got marked in red and
penalized. It was like the [Salem witch trials](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/a-brief-history-of-the-salem-witch-trials-175162489/) of 1692, only with a lot more red
ink spilled.

Upon graduating high school or college, students were trained to spot anything
that looked passive-ish and excise it. Or exorcise it. When desktop computers became commonplace, even grammar-checking software joined in the
anti-passive frenzy—automatically marking every passive-ish-looking verb with
a red underline and telling the user to change it to active voice. Computers,
of course, are the ultimate in following rules without regard to common sense.

## The End (not)

And that, dear Chen Li Yong, is why *some* English speakers (think they) don't like the
passive voice. But we're not all like that. Actually, most people don't care.
Most people still choose the passive or active according to whichever seems to suit
what they're trying to say, without even thinking about it. Many teachers try
to cultivate good judgement in their students, and many people do their best
to exercise good judgement in writing, choosing the active or passive voice not by any simple rule but
according to what's relevant, what they want to emphasize, what's clear, and
what sounds good.  Even anti-passive activists use the passive voice all the
time ([without noticing](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wikipedia_talk:Manual_of_Style&diff=prev&oldid=590003244)). It comes up in classes and writing guides
more than in real life. The only real trouble is that when many people *talk
about* how to revise a sentence, the mythology they were taught makes it hard
to converse about it intelligently.

But wait, the story's not over. Many people have noticed that all this fuss
over the passive voice is absurd.  A new anti-anti-passive activism is on the
rise among academics.  Even now, they're crafting a new mythology: about how
the passive voice became anathema.  They're [blaming Strunk & White](http://thecriticalreader.com/bad-advice-about-the-passive-voice-from-strunk-and-white/) for making
a rule against it, which Strunk & White [never did](https://books.google.com/books?id=sj5_wr6zIEcC&pg=PA34&dq=%22passive%20voice%22).  New prescriptions are justified
with "science" and Google Ngrams rather than custom, precedent, taste, and reasonable opinion.  Even now,
new forms of faux objectivity are taking root. Instead of resorting to the
passive voice, students who want to sound "objective" today report facts by
explicitly stating their source even when the source is irrelevant. In
another ten years, probably another substitute for choosing words thoughtfully will arise, and reasonable
people will ignore that, too.

## The Moral of the Story

So how does this affect you, a non-native speaker learning English?

Well, now you know that some of
what you are taught about English is nonsense. Now you know that respected
authorities contradict each other.

My
advice is to ignore the advice to eschew the passive, and remember that the
anti-passive activists are the crazy ones, not you. The passive voice is nearly always used innocently. It has many common uses, and is actually indispensible in English. Crusading against the passive voice because it *can* be abused makes as much sense as crusading against the present tense or the third person; those can be and are abused, too.

But you could reasonably disagree with my advice.
As you gain mastery of
English, you should gradually become more confident in choosing
how *you* want to use the language. You should explore different forms of
expression, read a variety of authors, see how flexible the grammar really is,
and develop your own style through experience—just as every native speaker
does.

---

*<sub>Actually, England was at war almost continuously during this time. This
is a fable. Historical facts have been adjusted where necessary to support
the moral. There never was a Golden Age, not even in regard to English grammar.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for a well written and concise answer! Oh, now I understand that people usually abuse passive voice to give half-truth, thinking that if they were given an active voice version of it, the person wouldn't be able to conceal the last part of the passive forms (for example, who shot?). I now realised that in my country, people are also usually abuse the passive voice to deliver half-truth as well, but nobody raise up the matter. I agree that I should have my own judgement in my mastery of English of whether I should use active or passive form depends on the context. Thank you very much!

Comment: @ChenLiYong Thank you for calling my answer concise! ;) Actually, the passive voice is most frequently used quite innocently. It has many common uses; it's actually indispensible in English. I didn't explain the ordinary uses of the passive voice in this answer, or it would have been twice as long! (I will add some of this comment to the answer, though.)

Comment: Ben a pleasure to read!  As answers go, it does have it's flaws - it's highly opinioned, inaccurate at times, long, etc., etc. but it's also wonderfully funny, deeply insightful at times, and cleverly constructed.  I think this answer is more suitable to people with a lot of expertise in English and not as suitable for learners, but I personally enjoyed it immensely!

Comment: @Brillig Thanks! I agree: it's opinionated and the style is too much for most learners. I'd like to see more answers to this question: it _is_ an important topic for learners, to get some awareness of the cultural ferments and fevers that surround this topic and how they distort the teaching they receive and even the advice they sometimes get from native speakers. There must be many good ways to answer it.

Comment: Ben, it's clearly important to you, and therefore natural for you to assume it would be important and interesting to everyone, but it could also be considered an overload of tangential information that ultimately distracts from the learning process. In terms of a Maslowian hierarchy, most learners are needing to gain security with their use of the language and perhaps some exploration of the next (emotional) level.  Your comments are asking them to try and self-actualize, or at least address self-esteem needs, prior to addressing more fundamental needs.  That's my opinion anyway.

Answer (score 6):

People recommend active voice over passive because, in general, active voice tends to result in sentences which are more concise and direct (short and easy to understand).  For instance:

ACTIVE

- I fixed the problem.
- John borrowed five dollars.
- Jesus wept.

Because of these qualities, active voice is generally preferred in business communication, in literary essays, and when the speaker wants to come across as more energetic.

However, passive voice also has it's place in the language, for instance, it is often preferable in scientific writings and when the subject is inferred, as you mention in your question: "Oranges are grown in warmer climates" is fine - it's completely unnecessary to say "Orange growers grow oranges in warmer climates."  But other passive constructions have clear disadvantages to the active alternatives; for instance:

PASSIVE

- The problem was fixed by me.
- Five dollars were borrowed by John.
- Weeping was done by Jesus.

As you mention in your comments there is in many countries a cultural preference against assigning responsibility, so passive construction is a way to avoid assigning any responsibility.  Returning to my examples above:

PASSIVE (with no responsibility assigned)

- The problem was fixed.
- Five dollars were borrowed.
- Weeping was done.

This type of responsibility-free construction is generally very annoying to native English speakers so I suggest you avoid it unless you don't like them and intentionally want to frustrate them.  A native English speaker generally prefers that:

- the first noun of a sentence be the agent
- that the agent proceeds the action (verb) in the sentence
- that any animation have an assigned agent (ie if weeping was done, who did it?)

Here is one study that was done on how language and responsibility interplay into how people think that may give you better insight on the differences between your view of the world and a typical native English speaker:  http://www.scielo.cl/pdf/signos/v46n83/a06.pdf

Comment: I think you've written an instructive answer here, but I'm not sure I agree with the assertion that "responsibility-free construction is generally very annoying to native English speakers." Actually, that kind of sentence does have its time and place. (It can be a good approach in marital discussions, for example – "You never do the dishes" might elicit a more defensive and hostile response than "The dishes are often left undone".)

Comment: Yes, I agree, and caveated that passive sentences have a place in English.  However, the question clearly asked to give some insight on "background cultural influence or thinking process" of native English speakers that prefer active voice in contrast to the questioner's stated background of coming from a society which prefers passive voice and is more conscientiously polite in it's normal construction than typical English.  I therefore wasn't concerned that he'd overlook opportunities to be polite using passive construction, and felt it was more important to answer his question head on.

Comment: I might also add that comments like "the dishes are often left undone" are sometimes considered passive/aggressive and not recommended by psychological writers I have read; instead, they usually recommend something like "I feel frustrated when I so often find the dishes are not done."  This sentence does not overly emphasize blame but it is an active construction, has a clear agent, the agent proceeds the action, etc.

Comment: I upvote your answer because I find it reasonable. But I believe the choice is influenced by register and clarity. See my comment under the OP.

Comment: Thanks.  Like you, I'm not a fan of Strunk and White.  I also recognize that many English speakers, even native speakers, struggle to understand active versus passive voice.  Confusion abounds, making constructive discussion difficult.

Comment: "Because of these qualities, active voice is generally preferred in business communication, in literary essays, and when the speaker wants to come across as more energetic." --> this was the _why_ that I'm looking for. After imagining it, yeah, I can see that using active voice probably can be seen as energetic and straightforward, and I also can see that in your crafted example, there are also situations that demand active form. "The problem was fixed." will be often followed with "by who?" This will not be a problem if the active form was used. For everything there's time and place. :)